# Can we not use input function in VS Code without enabling in Code Runner extension run in terminal..?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Can we not use input function in VS Code without enabling in Code Runner extension run in terminal..?

I am trying to run a program which contains an input function. But its not working when I am running the code. It just looks like its just frozen.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we not use input function in VS Code without enabling in Code Runner extension run in terminal..?

If you don't set the output to go to the terminal, Code Runner uses the Output panel, which has no input mechanism. So I'm pretty sure the answer to that question is yes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension to execute the Python script.

[image]

If you must use *Code Runner*, add the following settings to make the result output on the **TERMINAL** panel, because **OUTPUT** does not accept user input.

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```